# with-query-replace-color: macro or function?

Tags: elisp-macros

I'm trying to create my first macro. I often change the background color of the query-replace matched string in my script. I usually do:

```
(let* ((face 'query-replace)
       (bg (face-background face))) 
  (unwind-protect
      (progn
    (set-face-background face "gold")
    (perform-replace "^%+\n" ""  t t nil 1 nil (point-min) (point-max)))
    (set-face-background face bg)))
```

Now I'd like to have a macro to do that. Something like:

```
(with-query-replace-color "gold"
  (perform-replace "^%+\n" ""  t t nil 1 nil (point-min) (point-max)))
```

I tried with:

```
(defmacro with-query-replace-color (COLOR &rest body)
  "Change bg color in `perform-replace'..."
  (declare (indent 1))
  (let* ((face 'query-replace)
     (bg (face-background face)))
    `(unwind-protect
     (progn
       (set-face-background ,face ,COLOR)
       ,@body) 
       (set-face-background ,face ,bg))))
```

I get:

```
Symbol’s value as variable is void: query-replace.
```

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Should I use a function instead?

Comment: Why do you need a macro for that? Why won't a regular function do?

Comment: @wasamasa Because I don't know how to write functions that accept `(&rest body)` as argument. I thought it was non possible. Isn't so?

Comment: @wasamasa I edited the title of my question and added a second one to take in account what you pointed.

Comment: You can, but it wouldn't have the same effect (unless you were using a thunk).

Comment: Your error: not enough quoting (you actually don't need `face` variable, just write `'query-replace` in the macro body).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with:

```
(defmacro with-query-replace-color (COLOR &rest body)
  "Changes bg color in `perform-replace'..."
  (declare (indent 1))
  `(let* ((face `query-replace)
     (bg (face-background face))) 
      (unwind-protect
      (progn
        (set-face-background face ,COLOR)
        ,@body)
     (set-face-background face bg))))
```